# Edit BS4 to return none when table is not available in a webpage

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

The following code works when tag `h2` with the text  `"Content Logical definition"`is available in the html page, such as [https://www.hl7.org/fhir/valueset-account-status.html](http://www.hl7.org/fhir/valueset-account-status.html)

```
def extract_table(url):
                r = requests.get(url)
                soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
                h2 = soup.find(lambda elm: elm.name == 'h2' and 'Content Logical   Definition' in elm.text)
                div = h2.find_next_sibling('div')
                return div.find('table')
```

But for the following webpage that does not contain h2 with  `"Content Logical definition", such as https://www.hl7.org/fhir/valueset-cpt-all.html  returns the following error:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_next_sibling'
```

How I can edit the code to return non for table when there is no `h2 with content logical definition`in the webpage.

Comment: You might, for example move div.find('table') to variable, like `table = div.find('table')` and surround both lines (div above and table assignations) with try-catch block, returning table or None in case of AttributeError exception.

Comment: @justMe, thank you so much ! If you do not mind, would you please write down the code you explained? Thanks again !

Comment: alecxe code is just that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in two common ways:

- [`LBYL` - look before you leap](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-lbyl):

  ```
  h2 = soup.find(lambda elm: elm.name == 'h2' and 'Content Logical   Definition' in elm.text)
  return div.find_next_sibling('div').find('table') if h2 else None
  ```
- [`EAFP` - easier to ask for forgiveness than permission](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp):

  ```
  try:
      h2 = soup.find(lambda elm: elm.name == 'h2' and 'Content Logical   Definition' in elm.text)
      div = h2.find_next_sibling('div')
      return div.find('table')
  except AttributeError:
      return None
  ```